# Sonatype Nexus incompletely proxies external repository

Tags: proxy, maven, nexus

I'm currently attempting to set up a proxy repository (as described in the [Nexus guide](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-adding.html)) for the Bukkit repository, in order to build some dependent projects locally. I'm using the URL:

```
http://repo.bukkit.org/content/repositories/bukkit_repos/
```

It seems to be the right URL, but no matter my configuration, I can't seem to get Nexus to actually proxy any artifacts through the repository. I've tried:

- Using different IDs in the local Nexus version, both `bukkit` (my desired ID) and `bukkit_repos` (to match the remote repo)
- Changing the policy of the repo from Release to Snapshot, and even recreating the repo with the different policies
- Adding the URL above as a mirror
- Expiring the cache, rebuilding the index, and updating the index

No matter what I try, I can't get any artifacts to appear in the proxy. What am I missing?

Comment: Does that URL work as a repository in your settings.xml?  That'd be the first thing that I check to make sure it's "maven-friendly".

Comment: The build works when I place that URL in my `settings.xml` as a repository. What's more, after I woke up this morning, Nexus had proxied this repository; however, I can still produce this problem with new proxy repos. Is there just a several-hour lag involved in the proxy operation?